# Running an executable that reads input from a file and prints to another file

Tags: python

I am trying to run a file, map.py, from within a Python program. My code is as follows:

```
import sh

exe = sh.Command("./path/to/map.py")
file_in = open("./path/to/inputfile") #inputfile has no extension
out_file = "./path/to/outputfile" #outputfile has no extension
exe(_in=file_in, _out=out_file)
```

After running this code, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/vagrant/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sh.py", line 1427, in __call__
    return RunningCommand(cmd, call_args, stdin, stdout, stderr)
  File "/vagrant/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sh.py", line 774, in __init__
    self.wait()
  File "/vagrant/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sh.py", line 792, in wait
    self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/vagrant/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sh.py", line 815, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_255:

  RAN: /vagrant/exec/word_count/map.py

  STDOUT:


  STDERR:
```

Here is a dummy example of what map.py would be doing:

```
print("hi")
```

There should be some stdout stuff though. The program just doesn't seem to be running for me and I'm not sure why. I've been staring at this for hours, I would really appreciate the help!

Comment: You probably want to add more details.  For example, I ran

    echo "foo" > /tmp/infile;
    python -c 'import sh; exe = sh.Command("cat"); fi = open("/tmp/infile"); po = "/tmp/outfile"; exe(_in=fi, _out=po)';
   cat /tmp/outfile

and it worked fine

Comment: Can you post a very short dummy `map.py` that demonstrates the problem? There isn't much we can do otherwise.

Comment: One last note.  I would recommend `subprocess.Popen` in general.

Comment: sure, this is a dummy map.py: import sys; for line in sys.stdin: print("hey");

Comment: Was anything written to outputfile? It won't show on the screen because you redirected stdout. The program returned 255 for some reason... we just don't know why.

Comment: Oh, and put that example into the question so we can see spacing.

Comment: No, nothing gets written to outputfile for me.

Comment: Are you on Linux or OSX? I duplicated your problem but fixed it by adding the shebang `#!/usr/inb/env python3` to the top and making it executable. Seems `sh` isn't too talkative if the file isn't runnable.

Comment: If that's the problem let me know so I can make it the answer.

Comment: Yeah that doesn't seem to be working for me. I'm running on a Linux virtual machine right now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run that code in your current python shell, you should make the parent folder modules and import that file and access it directly.

If you want to run the file in a separate process and get the results use [subprocess.check_output](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output)

Comment: Why not use `sh`? It claims to be a `subprocess` replacement and it seems reasonable to use it.

Comment: I have to use sh, and I'm trying to give a Python executable input from the "inputfile" and have the Python executable output to "outputfile". It all has to happen within Python.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read from one file and write it to another. You could do something like this

```
input_f = open(input, 'r')
output_f = open('workfile', 'w')
lines = input_f.readlines()
for i in lines:
    #replicates whatever map.py does
    output_f.write(new_line)
    output_f.flush()
```

I think that will work for what you are trying to do.

Comment: I need to run map.py within the program within sh, because the code within map.py can be anything as long as it takes a file as input and outputs something. So this solution won't work.